# Why does 'bpy.context.object' return 'None' when accessed by an operator in a panel?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, add-on

[image: Display Mode of Object]

I wanted to switch between Display modes with hot keys.

And I decided to write my own operator for this and create a small add-on to be able to start using hot keys and switch between these modes.
The operator itself works.

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    bpy.context.object.display_type = 'TEXTURED'
    #bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

But when I started working with creating a button for my operator, there were problems.

```
class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Big Button:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.0
        row.operator("object.simple_operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*When I click on the button to apply my operator, an error appears:*

```
    Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\ui_panel.py", line 31, in execute

  File "\ui_panel.py", line 16, in main
    bpy.context.object.display_type = 'TEXTURED'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

What is the problem? Why, if you call the operator directly, then it works, and if through the button it throws an error? Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: For some reason bpy.context.object return None in script with button what call operator while if execute operator itself with debugging bpy.context.object it return selected object

Comment: I solve the problem, start from beginng creating the same script and it works, I did not fully understand what was the problem, but now it works

Comment: I start new try with templates, there are differences in poll function
`@classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None`

Comment: Maybe the problem was this

Comment: When accessing the context from the operator, you should use the `context` passed as a parameter of your method, not `bpy.context` since those can be different

Answer (score 2):

change following line in Panel

```
bl_context = "scene"
```

to

```
bl_context = "object"
```

context passed to draw function in Panels contains current active object only in object specific sections like 'object','data','physics','constraints' etc.

Comment: Would say this is also  specific to buttons context or the PROPERTIES area.  Other workarounds would be i) if the panel is for scene context then consider using `context.active_object` ii)  set the context pointer `UILayout.context_pointer_set("object", context.active_object)` to have `context.object` visible to operators.

Comment: IIRC it also has something to do with `area.pin_id`